# How to resolve Future[Any] in akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I've created a route:

```
post {
        path("validate" / Segment / Segment / Segment) { (userId, listId, prefix) =>
            parameters('filter.?) { filter =>
                def result = (
                    phoneValidationActor ? ValidateUserList(userId.toInt, listId.toInt, prefix.toUpperCase, filter)
                )
                complete(result)
            }
        }
    }
```

And an actor

```
class PhoneNumberActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    import PhoneNumberActor._

    def receive: Receive = {
        case ValidateUserList(userId, listId, prefix, filter) =>
            sender() ! validateUserList(userId, listId, prefix, filter)
    }
}
```

And a receive function for actor

```
def validateUserList(user_id: Int, list_id: Int, prefix: String, filter: Option[String]): Future[Seq[PhoneNumber]] = {
    val prefixTrim = prefix.trim
    val listContact = new ListContactRepository
    listContact.getAllContacts(user_id, list_id).map { lines =>
        lines.map { line =>
            validateNumber(line.phone, prefixTrim)
        }
    }
}
```

In route, result is parsed as `Future[Any]` instead of `Future[Seq[PhoneNumber]]`
Need help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mapTo` on result of the ask call.

`(phoneValidationActor ? ValidateUserList(userId.toInt, listId.toInt, prefix.toUpperCase, filter))).mapTo[Seq[PhoneNumber]]`

and handle future inside the actor to avoid ClassCastException

```
class PhoneNumberActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    import PhoneNumberActor._

    def receive: Receive = {
        case ValidateUserList(userId, listId, prefix, filter) =>
          val theSender = sender() //do not call this method in callback function onSuccess as it breaks actor principles and can send message to a wrong sender 
          validateUserList(userId, listId, prefix, filter).onSuccess { phoneNumbers => 
            theSender ! phoneNumbers
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do
`def result = (phoneValidationActor ? ValidateUserList(userId.toInt, listId.toInt, prefix.toUpperCase, filter)).mapTo[Seq[PhoneNumber]]`
But received
`java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise to scala.collection.Seq`
I'm wondering validateUserList already resulting in as `Future[Seq[PhoneNumber]]`. though it's not working

Comment: The reason is that your `validateNumber` function returns are future. You need to return `Seq[PhoneNumber]`

Comment: `Future[Seq[PhoneNumber]]` is returned by mongodb for its records. So if there's effective solution for this

Comment: @SujitBaniya use map on Future or pipe pattern to resolve handling of the future inside of an actor.

Comment: @SujitBaniya I'll update the answer with an example as soon as I get to my laptop

Comment: Thank you! will try till then

Comment: @SujitBaniya you should probably consider using one asynchronous boundary: Actor vs Future. Use just one of this. You could call `listContact.getAllContacts(user_id, list_id)` directly from Route

Comment: Akka ask pattern produces a Future that is not much different from a Future returned by mongo driver. So, it's not blocking. But you need to consider where Future produced by driver runs, ie ExecutionContext. It will dictate how many Futures can run in parallel

Comment: Received: `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast scala.util.Success to scala.collection.Seq` when implementing above code and
`complete((phoneValidationActor ? ValidateUserList(userId.toInt, listId.toInt, prefix.toUpperCase, filter)).mapTo[Seq[PhoneNumber]])`

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Ivan Stanislavciuc said, you need to add the `mapTo`  method to safely cast a Future to an expected type which in this case is `[Seq[PhoneNumber]]`.
for your route I'd update it to something like such:

```
post {
    path("validate" / Segment / Segment / Segment) { (userId, listId, prefix) =>
        parameters('filter.?) { filter =>
            val result = 
                (phoneValidationActor ? ValidateUserList(userId.toInt, listId.toInt, prefix.toUpperCase, filter)).mapTo[Seq[PhoneNumber]]
            onSuccess(result) { maybeResult =>
              complete(maybeResult)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you'd like to handle a Success and Failure you can use `onComplete` in place of `onSuccess` and have something like:

```
                onComplete(result) {
                  case scala.util.Success(res) => complete(res)
                  case scala.util.Failure(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, ex)}
```